# No mail is receiving by admin after new order placed - Woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Hi i am using the `woocommerce` plugin for my `WordPress` website. When a customer place a new order the email is going to his/her id but the notification mail is not received by admin. I tried different codes and plugin for making this thing workable. This is the plugin i installed `WP-Mail-SMTP` and also used some of the code like

```
function new_customer_registered_send_email_admin($user_login) {
ob_start();
do_action('woocommerce_email_header', 'New customer registered');
$email_header = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();
do_action('woocommerce_email_footer');
$email_footer = ob_get_clean();

woocommerce_mail(
get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
get_bloginfo('name').' - New customer registered',
$email_header.'<p>The user '.esc_html( $user_login ).' is registered to the website</p>'.$email_footer
);
}
add_action('new_customer_registered', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin')
```

is there anyway to do this

Answer (score 0):

You should send a mail with woocommerce mailer function see the below code try something like

```
function user_reg($user_login) {
$subject = 'WC Send Mail Test';

// load the mailer
$mailer = WC()->mailer();
$mailer->send( get_option( 'admin_email' ), $subject, $mailer->wrap_message( $subject, 'a test message' ), '', '' );

}
add_action('new_customer_registered', 'user_reg');
```

to see it helps :)

Thanks.